# Huge table in a Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

if you have millions of entries in a mysql table, you often want to manipulate it with a hexadecimal primary key (in practice you do a md5(name)). The queries are then much faster.

Is there a way to do this with Django?
If not, the usual int primary key isn't limitating? 
How to specify that you want a big integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use whatever you like as the primary key in Django.  Just add `primary_key=True` to the model arguments.  E.g.

```
foo = models.CharField(max_length=36, primary_key=True)
```

Here are the [Django docs on this topic](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#id1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: and you can only have one primary key per class?

Comment: You can only have one primary key per _table_.  That's a database thing, not a Django thing.  However, the database generally allows you to make a primary key of multiple columns.  I'm not sure what the behaviour would be if you specified two primary keys in your model.  Why not try it out and see? :-)